# is there a way to display pine script Alerts on/off (dynamically) in TABLES format?

Tags: pine-script

is there a way in pine script to display Alerts on/off (dynamically) in TABLES format?
cant find it here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This code only triggers an alert when the realtime bar closes, and prints the alert's state using a table:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_print(_txt) => 
    var table _t = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 1)
    if barstate.islast
        table.cell(_t, 0, 0, _txt, text_color = color.silver)

cond = close > open
if barstate.isconfirmed
    if cond
        alert("Alert")
        f_print("Alert ON")
    else
        f_print("Alert OFF")
```